# Elastic beanstalk worker environment - how do I figure out why all messages go to dead letter queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I just started using a worker environment in elastic beanstalk. As I understand it, the environment listens to a queue then POSTs the message to a url that you specify. I created a POST endpoint and specified the url in the configure section of elasticbeanstalk.

However, when I send a message to the queue it isn't being posted to the instance. All of the messages go to the dead letter queue. When I click 'view messages' on the dead letter queue and poll, it shows all the messages, but no error or anything that would give me some hint as to why they're failing.

Does anyone have any tips on how to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the endpoint I specified required a parameter. Removing the parameter fixed the problem.

Leaving this here in case anyone else ever runs into this problem.